# What is the name of this piece component?

Tags: power-supply, identification

I'm repairing my DVD pioneer and I need to buy this piece, could you tell me her name and where can I buy it? On some site?

Highlighted in red color

[image]

Comment: That's an inductor. But you have much bigger problems that those inductors, which are probably fine.

Comment: Those are inductors. Most likley part of the powersupply consisting of L1202 switch regulator in the middle.

Comment: to clarify: I see two capacitors (bottom left and top right) in this circuit that have failed and vented. Those need to be replaced before this has any hope of working.

Comment: It's also worth noting that asking "where can I buy this" is a shopping question and considered off topic on ee.se.

Comment: Sorry for the "off topic" but do you know where I can buy? I do not find that piece in my city.

I soldered it and changed the 2 capacitors and it worked again. But she warmed and let go again.

Comment: Thanks for adding a good quality picture, btw. Sharp, correctly cropped, and scaled. Sadly, those are rare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those are surface mount power inductors.

They are pretty rugged, just thick copper wire. If they are broken, chances are something else is too. I can easily see that your capacitors are completely blown.

Where to buy them is off topic for [many reasons](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).